# Could not export identity from the keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, keychain, provisioning-profile

While exporting Code signing identity from Xcode 5, Preferences->Accounts I get the error upon saving "Could not export identity from the keychain".

What can it be?

Edit:

The login.keychain is unlocked. The account of the profile I want to export is connected and also present in login.keychain.

Console.app output:

```
31/05/14 15:23:06,879 Xcode[489]: Error, Could not export identity from the keychain: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.
```

Comment: does "`Console.app`" give any helpful hints as to what might be going on here?  How many accounts and logins and developer accounts do you have?

Comment: I have only one account and the password is definitely correct for that one. However doesn't work. Is it for sure the password I use for developer.apple?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The solution is to lock the **login keychain**, so you can actually be prompted for the keychain password and then export it. If it's unlocked I just keep getting the error despite the password shall be correct - the keychain is unlocked, right?

So lock and export.

Comment: Thanks for this. Adding a comment for future googlers.... This also works when you are trying to add a certificate and get the error 'The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.'

Answer (score 2):

Xcode needs permission from the login keychain to export the identities. Are you sure you are providing the correct password for **login keychain**?

I tried to replicate this issue and got the error by entering the wrong password for login keychain.

To double check, go to keychain access from your machine and try to unlock the login keychain.

If you have already unlocked the keychain, Xcode won't prompt you for the password. Then you will just have to enter the password for the exported identities.

Comment: it is not the case. The keychain is unlocked, the password for the exported identities can be anything, right? However still I got:
27/05/14 12:59:16,119 Xcode[94584]: Error, Could not export identity from the keychain: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.